# How to predict translations (decode) for IBM models in nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm fairly new to the NLTK API and wanted to get started with the simplistic IBM Model 1, which does word-level translations. This is what I did so far, with the help of the [NLTK API documentation](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/ibm1.html).

```py
from nltk.translate.ibm1 import IBMModel1
from nltk.translate import AlignedSent

def get_text(filename):
    senteces = []
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for sentence in f:
            sentences.append(sentence.split())
    return sentences

src_sentences = get_text('source.txt')
trg_sentences = get_text('target.txt')

bitext = []
for i in range(len(src_sentences)):
    bitext.append(AlignedSent(src_sentences[i], trg_sentences[i]))

ibm1 = IBMModel1(bitext, 5)
```

Now that `IBMModel1` has been created, I'm unsure how to perform the [decoding](https://www.statmt.org/book/slides/06-decoding.pdf), ie. predicting translations from a test set. I can't seem to find this on the documentation as well.

In simple words, I want to obtain a predicted translation, given a random source sentence using this model. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

See these examples at https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.translate.ibm1.html#nltk.translate.ibm1.IBMModel1

```
>>> bitext = []
>>> bitext.append(AlignedSent(['klein', 'ist', 'das', 'haus'], ['the', 'house', 'is', 'small']))
>>> bitext.append(AlignedSent(['das', 'haus', 'ist', 'ja', 'groß'], ['the', 'house', 'is', 'big']))
>>> bitext.append(AlignedSent(['das', 'buch', 'ist', 'ja', 'klein'], ['the', 'book', 'is', 'small']))
>>> bitext.append(AlignedSent(['das', 'haus'], ['the', 'house']))
>>> bitext.append(AlignedSent(['das', 'buch'], ['the', 'book']))
>>> bitext.append(AlignedSent(['ein', 'buch'], ['a', 'book']))

>>> ibm1 = IBMModel1(bitext, 5)

>>> print(ibm1.translation_table['buch']['book'])
```

Comment: I did come across these examples, however, this is not what I intend to do.
`>>> print(ibm1.translation_table['buch']['book'])`
This simply returns the translation table of 'buch' and 'book'.
I am looking for something that can predict the translation using the trained model (`ibm1` in this case) ie. input 'buch' should give output 'book'